# Relating UIButton

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

I am building a sort of check sheet with many uibuttons, that I am adding using code (not IB).  I would like to have it that when certain buttons are selected, other buttons cannot be selected.  For example, I have one row of buttons that will be LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH.  I don't want it to be possible for the user to select 2 of the options (if they want to change their choice thats fine, just no 2 at a time).

I know the general structure of my methods, and here is what I have so far:

`-(void)addButtons` This is where I will populate the view with buttons (just showing one button here but there are many):

```
-(void)addButtons{

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(209, 54, 127, 18);
    button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [imageView addSubview:button];

}
```

---

`-(void)clicked:(UIButton *)sender`  This is the method that will be called when a button is clicked.  I want it to submit itself as a parameter.  The button will then change its appearance to signify it has been clicked.  The reason I am making it transparent is because I have the buttons on top of an image and you need to see what underneath them.  I also don't think `sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];` will work like I want it to but thats beside the point.

```
-(void)clicked:(UIButton *)sender{

    sender.alpha = 0.5;
    sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [self setRelatedButtons:sender];

}
```

---

`-(void)setRelatedButtons'`  And this is the method where I will ensure that only one button per 'set' is selected

```
-(void)setRelatedButtons:(UIButton *)sender{

    //since I know this button is clicked
    //set related buttons to unclicked

}
```

---

**To sum up everything**, here is what I am wondering:

1)  How can I set a button's appearance to stay selected ?

2)  What should I pass to my `clicked` and `setRelatedButtons` methods to identify the current button?  Right now I have the button itself but is there something better?

3)  What is the best way to relate certain buttons?  I could use an array for each set of buttons, but I hope there is better way.  Could I potentially use a `typedef` ? (never used one of those before)

Comment: This is actually 3 questions.

Comment: On your `clicked:` method use this:  `((UIButton *)sender).backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a button's appearance to stay selected, you can do a lot of different things. You could change the label, the background color, the text color, whatever. [This](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html) might help with that. Just so you know, if you want to submit this to the app store you can't use actual selection state to show that a button has been selected (so don't do `button.selected = YES`). Apple specifically prohibits this.

If you want to deselect all other buttons just set all buttons' appearance to not selected when one button is clicked. AFTER you do that, set the button that sent the message to selected (with whatever you decided from above). Put your buttons in an array so that you can just make a for loop to access all of them (`NSMutableArray` will be helpful with `addObject`).

To answer your second question, passing the `UIButton *` itself is fine (you're actually just passing a pointer). This has the advantage of being able to do things like `[button doSomething]` instead of having to find it in an array or other data type.

I'm not quite sure what your third question is asking, but you could subclass `UIButton` if you want. An array for each set of buttons actually sounds like a good idea. You could even do an array of arrays. Or you could make a custom holder class with arrays in it with methods to return what you want.

If you use arrays, you could pass an integer to your `addButton` method that tells the method which array (or part of the complex array) to put the button in.

Also, try to keep your questions to one thing; people are MUCH less likely to answer your question if they have to answer multiple questions. You can ask as many questions as you want, just ask them separately.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will keep my questions separate in the future